# Neo4j: "does not contain" queries

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to find all users whose gender does not contain the string "male". I expect the result of this query to be those users who have not specified a gender.

Users and genders are separate nodes, connected like so:

```
(user node) - [:gender] -> (gender node)
```

For some users, the gender relationship does not exist

I ran this query:

```
MATCH (g:genders) 
WHERE g.gender =~ ".*male.*" 
WITH g MATCH (u:users) 
WHERE NOT (u)-[:gender]->(g) 
RETURN COUNT(u);
```

The problem with this query is that it returns all the users in my database because the WHERE NOT clause is doing an OR comparison instead of AND ie it is finding all users whose gender is not male or not female, which is all users in my db.

How can I make it an AND query? I would like a solution that does not assume the end node (in this case the gender node) to always have only two possible values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this query do what you intend?

```
MATCH (u:user)
WITH COLLECT(u) AS cu
UNWIND cu AS u
MATCH (u)-[:gender]->(g:gender) WHERE g.gender =~ ".*male.*"
WITH cu, COLLECT(u) AS cv
RETURN REDUCE(s=[], x IN cu | CASE WHEN NOT x IN cv THEN s + x ELSE s END) AS result;
```

It removes users who have a gender containing "male" from the total set of users.

Comment: I want to find the matching user nodes, not just the count.

Comment: Also, not that it helps my problem, but just wanted to point to you that you could replace this entire block: MATCH (u:user)
WITH COLLECT(u) AS cu
WITH cu, LENGTH(cu) AS total_u
UNWIND cu AS u 

with match (u:user) with count(u) as total_u

Comment: You are absolutely correct. But please see my new answer, which returns the desired user nodes -- it actually needs to create a collection.